# How to design database to let users enter and save recipes

Tags: php, html, mysql, database-design

For an university project I need to do the following:

1. Let the user enter ingredients via HTML form, process it via PHP into my MySQL database. For Example:
   The user enters EGG and QUANTITY and CALORIES.
2. Let the user make recipes out of these ingredients. So another form with recipename and ingredients.

Now my question is: How can I connect these tables in a proper manner? So that tablerecipe with recipename knows repiceid 1 consists of 3 eggs, 100g beef and 300g cheese?

I read about lookup tables, but I don't understand them. Any help would be appreciated.

My table structure looks like this so far:

[image: Database diagram]

Comment: @kittykittybangbang — Many to many. A recipe has many ingredients. An ingredient can be used by many different recipes. Throw in varying quantities for complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each recipe will have multiple ingredients, and each ingredient will belong to only one recipe, then you have a **One-to-Many** relationship. You should define your tables like this:

```
+----------------+                                 +------------------+
| recipes        |                                 | ingredients      |
+----------------+                                 +------------------+
| recipe_id      <----------------+                | ingredient_id    |
| recipe_name    |                |                | ingredient_name  |
|                |                +----------------+ recipe_id        |
|                |                                 |                  |
|                |                                 |                  |
|                |                                 |                  |
|                |                                 |                  |
|                |                                 |                  |
+----------------+                                 +------------------+
```

Notice how the `ingredients` table has a `recipe_id` that points to a recipe in the `recipes` table. When you want to query all the ingredients that belong to a recipe, you could query it like this:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    recipes r 
    INNER JOIN ingredients i WHERE i.recipe_id = r.recipe_id
```

However, this is probably not what you want because you might want to use an ingredient more than once. In this case, each ingredient can belong to more than one recipe and each recipe can have more than one ingredient. This is a **Many-to-Many** relationship. You should define your tables like this:

```
+----------------+                                 +------------------+
| recipes        |                                 | ingredients      |
+----------------+                                 +------------------+
| recipe_id      <---+                          +--> ingredient_id    |
| recipe_name    |   |                          |  | ingredient_name  |
|                |   |                          |  |                  |
|                |   |                          |  |                  |
|                |   |                          |  |                  |
|                |   |                          |  |                  |
|                |   |                          |  |                  |
|                |   |                          |  |                  |
+----------------+   |                          |  +------------------+
                     |                          |
                     |  +--------------------+  |
                     |  | recipe_ingredients |  |
                     |  +--------------------+  |
                     |  | id                 |  |
                     +--+ recipe_id          |  |
                        | ingredient_id      +--+
                        | quantity           |
                        | type               |
                        |                    |
                        |                    |
                        |                    |
                        |                    |
                        +--------------------+
```

Notice the extra table. This is sometimes called a **bridge** table and it associates a `recipe_id` with an `ingredient_id`. In this way, more than one ingredient can be associated with a recipe, and more than one recipe can be associated with an ingredient. I also added two extra columns to the bridge table that adds more information to the relationship. I added a `quantity` which is the amount of that ingredient to use, and a `type` which can be used to define the type of measurement (i.e. cups, grams, teaspoons, etc). When you want to query all the ingredients that belong to a recipe in this case, you could query it like this:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    recipes r 
    INNER JOIN ingredients_recipes ir ON ir.recipe_id=r.recipe_id 
    INNER JOIN ingredients i ON i.ingredient_id=ir.ingredient_id
```